# CSS: Preventing single symbols from wrapping to a new line

Tags: html, css

I'm presenting a long list of links wrapped in a div with middle dots separating each item (specifically, `[space]&middot;[space]` between each link). Occasionally, a dot appears at the beginning of a line, as shown here:

```
link · link · link · link · link · link · link · link · link · link · link · 
link · link · link · link · link · link · link · link · link · link · link · 
· link · link · link · link · link · link · link  · link  · link  · link  · link
```

Is there a way to prevent this? I've tried various `white-space` property values. Right now, each link is wrapped inside a `<span>` tag that uses `whiite-space: pre-wrap;` in its class, which so far has given the best results (i.e., the fewest wrapped dots).

Alternatively, if there's a better way to display such a list, I'm open the suggestions.

Comment: set width of your div to a particular value?

Comment: Am not understanding your question here

Comment: How can this happen unless you have a link with no link text?  Can you post your html? Your example shows two dots in a row with no link in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all your links have link text, you need the dot to stay on the same line as the preceding link.

A simple fix is to use a non-breaking space in your mark-up:

```
<a href="">link</a>&nbsp;&midot;
```

or use pseudo elements:

```css
a:after {
       content:'\A0\B7'; /* Hex codes for nbsp and midot */
}
```

```html
<a href"">link</a><a href"">link</a><a href"">link</a><a href"">link</a>
```

Comment: I used the pseudo elements and they worked like a charm. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could add the "dot" using pseudo content. Using an `:after` selector, it would never fall to the next line alone...

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 150px;
}

#wrapper span:after {
  content: ".";
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <span>link</span>
  <span>link</span>
  <span>link</span>
  <span>link</span>
  <span>link</span>
  <span>link</span>
  <span>link</span>
  <span>link</span>
  <span>link</span>
  <span>link</span>
  <span>link</span>
  <span>link</span>
  <span>link</span>
  <span>link</span>
  <span>link</span>
</div>
```